# problem with table into section of accordion jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i'm trying to create a table into a accordion but although i set into the table the width, i could make it fit into the section of accordion resulting of this

**this is the accordion closed**
[image]

**this is the accordion open: note's that when it's open the table inside the section doesn't fit into the width and for consecuense add scrollbars**

[image]

```
<div id="accordion" style="display: block; " class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset ui-accordion-icons" role="tablist">
    <h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-active ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><a href="#">algo</a></h3>
    <div id="indicator-65" class="indicatorLayer ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" style="display: block; height: 323px; " role="tabpanel">
        <table border="1" style="width:400px;float:left">
        <tbody><tr><td><p> <span class="formatText">Nombre de la capa: </span><label class="accordLblName">algo</label> </p><p> <span class="formatText">Imagen de los marcadores: </span></p><div id="5" class="accordImage" style="height:60px;background:url(assets/banderadepaz2.gif);background-repeat:no-repeat;margin-left:300px;margin-right:300px;"></div><p> <span class="formatText">Descripcion de la capa: </span><label class="accordLblDescrip">sklñasfjaslfñd </label></p><p><span class="formatText">Mensaje a mostrar: </span></p><div class="undefined"><p> <span class="fieldText">cantidad de fallas</span>  asdfasdfasdf</p></div></td><td> <label for="parameters" class="formatText">Elige el parametro que rige el indicador</label> <select name="parameters" id="sltParameters"><option value="1">Distrito Capital</option> </select>
        </td></tr></tbody></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

thanks and i hope an answer

Comment: can you post a better screenshot that shows more? can't really understand what the problem is from that pic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `<div>` tag inside your code:

```
<div id="5" class="accordImage" style="height:60px;background:url(assets/banderadepaz2.gif);background-repeat:no-repeat;margin-left:300px;margin-right:300px;"></div>
```

This has 300px margins on either side, which makes it take up 600px inside the table cell. That overrides your 400px.

I would place that image like this:

```
<div style="height:60px; width: WIDTH_OF_IMG_IN_PX; margin: 0 auto; background: url(assets/banderadepaz2.gif) no-repeat;"></div>
```

Comment: hi and thanks for asking, but if i removed the style of my div that have the image looks the same and also lost the margins of the div

Comment: @Jorge I really can't see anything else that could cause the problem. Try just deleting the `margin-left:300px;margin-right:300px;` part, and see what happens. I tested it and the table just popped back to 400px.